# How can I make a query to print sold out products? [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm new to databases. So, I got two tables `product` and `supplier`, and I need to make a query that prints the sold out products alongside some supplier information.

`product` table:

| Product_ID | Product_Name | Quantity | Supplier_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | water | 0 | 11 |
| 2 | Milk | 26 | 12 |
| 3 | eggs | 8 | 12 |
| 4 | 5L water | 19 | 11 |
| 5 | water gallon | 0 | 11 |

`supplier` table:

| Supplier_ID | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Pure life | 55555555 |
| 22 | Dairy | 77777777 |
| 33 | Nivea | 66666666 |

My work so far:

```
SELECT product.Product_ID, 'product.Product_Name', product.Quantity,
'supplier.Supplier_Name', supplier.Supplier_Phone
FROM product, supplier
INNER JOIN supplier S ON supplier.Supplier_ID = product.Supplier_ID
WHERE (Quantity = 0)
GROUP BY 'product.Product_Name';
```

The output:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'product.Supplier_ID' in 'on clause'

the desired output:

| Product_Name | Quantity | Supplier_Name | Supplier_Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| water | 0 | Pure life | 55555555 |
| water gallon | 0 | Pure life | 55555555 |

Comment: Change `FROM product, supplier` to `FROM product` you are referencing the supplier in the JOIN you dont need to do both

Comment: And you use backticks and not single quotes around tabe/column names

Comment: Could you please add the desired output? It's unclear if you are using a group by you don't need or if you are missing to create a sum. You could if possible also add more rows to your example to make it more clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the following issues in your query:

- in the `SELECT` clause, quotes will make MySQL understand you want some strings instead of referencing table fields: substitute backticks in place of quotes (or you can skip them completely in your case)
- in the `FROM` clause, there are references to three tables `product, supplier INNER JOIN supplier S`, instead what you need is put the word `INNER JOIN` between the names of the two tables `product` and `supplier`
- the `GROUP BY` clause, is not needed if you're not using an [aggregation function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) (like `MAX`, `SUM`, `GROUP_CONCAT`, etc...) inside the `SELECT` statement

Here's a snippet of how your query should look like:

```
SELECT 
    product.Product_ID, 
    `product.Product_Name`, 
    product.Quantity,
    `supplier.Supplier_Name`, 
    supplier.Supplier_Phone
FROM 
    product 
INNER JOIN 
    supplier 
ON 
    supplier.Supplier_ID = product.Supplier_ID
WHERE 
    product.Quantity = 0
```

Comment: still shows this: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'product.Product_Name' in 'field list'

Comment: There are some correct points noted in this answer, but I think the desired output must be made clear before giving an answer that is really helpful.